# What should have been the close reason for this question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, declined-flags

I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23412342/773623) with a custom flag as it's a pretty basic java question that doesn't fall into any other category IMO. The declined answer I got was `declined - Please use standard close votes or flags for this.`

Looking at the possible other flags, I can't find any that fits "User doesn't even understand the basics of Java, or programming in general for that instance, to ask a question that adds value to SO at this point. This is a question that shouldn't be asked as it's Java 101".

- It's not spam.
- It's not offensive.
- It's not a duplicate (well maybe    but all the questions would be closed)

under other reasons...

- it's still not a duplicate (?? Twice duplication option... that option is    a duplicate of the other)
- It is on topic since there's no minimum understanding needed for the question to be on topic
- It's pretty clear what is being asked
- It isn't too broad, the error is pretty obvious,
- It's not opinion based

and

- It's not low quality, it got a clear question and code.

So I was thinking the last flag was the only option I had to close this question but it seems I was wrong... or was I?

Comment: Why do you feel that basic questions should be closed?  Why do you think if it doesn't fit into the standard close reasons a moderator should step in and close it?

Comment: There used to be an option to say that the person asking the question should have a minimal understanding of what he was trying to do. This option seems to have disappeared. IMO, this question should be closed not because it's a basic question, but because the answer is too trivial and *too specific*: **the answer won't help anyone else but the OP.**

Comment: @bluefeet Unless I don't understand SO goals, not knowing that assigning a `String` to a `Customer` variable isn't helpful to anyone that have a basic understanding of programming. The code doesn't even compile in a IDE. Bruno pretty much sum my feeling.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau SO is for questions about programming which you state yourself above about the question _it got a clear question and code_, just because it is a basic question doesn't mean that the it should be closed. If you can't find a valid close reason, then what do you want the moderators to use as a reason?

Comment: @bluefeet I don't even feel it's a basic question, it's a lack of basic or minimum understanding of programming, it's a question someone, in the first few classes of programming 101 would ask and never ask again in a lifetime.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Again that isn't a valid reason to close a question.  When you are flagging for a moderator you are asking for us to step and in handle something that can't be handled by the community.  If there isn't a valid close reason that is provided, why do you think a moderator needs to step in?

Comment: @bluefeet It might falls under the one sevenseacat asnwered with, I'll see if it does even it it's a borderline reason. If there's isn't a valid close reasons in the options and the question needs to be closed, there's no other option for me than flagging for moderator attention. What else can I do if a question that doesn't belong on SO needs to be closed and no flagging options fits the reason? There's no other tool available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have limited knowledge of Java, but to me it looks like it should get a close vote with the reason:

*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: And where is that reason in the flag options?

Comment: I didn't say flag, I said close vote. And it appears on the off-topic list of close reasons.

Comment: Alright, seems like a good flag to use indeed.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: flag -> close for another reason -> off-topic -> can't be reproduced.