# Are self-answered questions with a very narrow scope on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375785/first-month-of-quarter-given-month-in-python) earlier this evening. At first glance it was a clear *"I can has teh codes?"*, but the OP self-answered.

I am aware of existing resources like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
- [What are limitations on self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235177/what-are-limitations-on-self-answered-questions)

To my mind, self-answered questions don't get a pass from the site quality guidelines; this would not be an acceptable question had the OP not answered it, and the fact that they did doesn't make it so. However, the votes on comments suggest a split of feeling each way. So is there a consensus: are questions like this on-topic? If not, should that be clearer in the Help Center?

Comment: [unlikely to help future readers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253266/839601)?

Comment: @gnat well I think so, but the OP's comment and three votes on it disagree!

Comment: I've improved the quality of the question, hope that helps! Again, would really like to see the many solutions you came up with. Would be useful for all the people who took the time to upvote the question, the answers, and provide helpful comments that improved the final solution.

Comment: @user2932774 I have posted the fastest I came up with

Comment: If you google "first month of quarter" even *without* mentioning Python, the question's already on the first page.  This could well make the question useful to those with the same question regarding other programming languages (if they are willing to unravel a little Python syntax) and makes this a valuable question.

Comment: It's already on the first page just like would automatically be any trivial localized enough question. Asking such a question on SO doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a difference between "this question is not very good" and "this question is off-topic".

By saying the question is off-topic, you are saying the question should be closed.  And I don't see anything to suggest it is off-topic enough to close it.  It doesn't seem to be too broad, and the question is perfectly clear.  The existing close votes are not correct in my opinion.

All that being said, you are absolutely correct that self-answered questions do not exempt anyone from the question quality guidelines, so you should feel free to moderate it as you would any other low quality post - that is downvote.

In short, a poor quality (or lazy) question is not a close reason, but it can be a downvote reason.

Answer (score 74):

A self-answered question should be clearly stated, and not be so specific as to
be unlikely to help others. But I don't think we should insist that
self-answered questions *show research in the question* because the result of
research is shown in the answer. The fact that the OP answered the question
shows that not only an effort was made, but also that the OP's efforts succeeded.

[This similar prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1406131/190597), with
currently has 28 upvotes 1 downvote and 5957 views, shows that there is an
interest in finding which quarter a date is in. That two earlier answers were
buggy shows the answer is not totally trivial.

The more we know the harder it is to sympathize with people who know less. More
and more things seem trivial. But we need to fight this urge to call things
trivial *just because we know the answer*. If we don't fight this urge, then in
theory any question that is asked could be closed simply because five other
people already know the answer and think you should be able to figure it out
too. Since there is no objective way to define what is trivial, you are free to
decide for yourself what you think deserves that classification. I merely wish
to urge that we have some patience with others especially when they show they
are trying by answering their own question.

Comment: +1 For "But we need to fight this urge to call things trivial just because we know the answer."

Comment: Yes, we do need to fight it - it has become a worryingly common trend on this site.

Comment: I don't ask a lot of questions because I dig very deep before asking.  The [most popular question I've ever asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466597/windows-service-system-timers-timer-not-firing) ended up being self-answered.  It has over 11K views and a fair number of upvotes on both the question and the answer.  Obviously people find this helpful.  I don't think a self-answered question should be closed just because it is self-answered nor because it requires specific code.  If a problem is solved, and if that problem might be experienced by others, then let the question stand!